# Can you write a function to create further functions in Python?

Tags: python

I am working on writing a repeatable script that uses the scipy optimize package. As part of this, you need to create functions of constraints. I am wanting to create a repeatable script that allows me to create the right number of constraint functions, based on a variable number of inputs.

For example:

```
def constraintx1(x):
    return (x2c2*(x[1]**2))+(x1c2*x[1]) + maxresponsec2
def constraintx2(x):
    return (x2c3*(x[2]**2))+(x1c3*x[2]) + maxresponsec3
def constraintx3(x):
    return (x2c4*(x[3]**2))+(x1c4*x[3]) + maxresponsec4

constraints = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun':constraintx1},
               {'type':'ineq', 'fun':constraintx2},
               {'type':'ineq', 'fun':constraintx3}]
```

all the x2c2, x1c2 and maxresponsec2 are coming from an input table defined earlier as curvestable.

These are some of my constraint functions, for 3 input variables. However, with another project, I might need to repeat this for 12 variables and I am hoping to create a loop that will generate the right number of constraint functions, based on a counter. I have been looking around but havent been able to find anything yet. I am hoping that there is something along the lines of:

```
numberofvariables = len(someinput)
constraints = []
for g in range(0,numberofvariables):
    def constraintg (x):
        return curvestable.iloc[g,1]*(x[0]**2))+(curvestable.iloc[g,2]*x[0]) + curvestable.iloc[g,4]
    constraints = constraints.append([{'type':'ineq', 'fun':constraintg}])
    next
```

I also need to point out I am an extreme amateur in coding so not sure if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = len(someinput)
ct = curvetable
constraints = [lambda x: ct.iloc[g,1]*(x[0]**2))+(ct.iloc[g,2]*x[0])+ ct.iloc[g,4] for g in range(n)]
```

This involves using two key python elements:

1. lambda expression, this addresses the core of your question - create functions using functions
2. list comprehension, this just makes code cleaner than for-loop plus append

Additionally, since your curvetable(renamed to ct to make code shorter) is a `DataFrame`, you can use the `apply` function, but I don't want to jam too much tricks to distract from the main point - lambda expression

Comment: lambdas really add nothing here

Answer (score 1):

You should check out python `closure` functions.

```
def constraint_func_maker(x2c2, x1c2, maxresp):
    def constraint_func(x):
        return (x2c2 * (x[1] ** 2)) + (x1c2 * x[1]) + maxresp
    return constraint_func
```